# my code to count prime twins within a range of (2, n) only works with certain values of N

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, math

[challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/596549c7743cf369b900021b/train/python)

> A twin prime is a prime number that is either 2 less or 2 more than another prime number—for example, either member of the twin prime pair (41, 43). In other words, a twin prime is a prime that has a prime gap of two. Sometimes the term twin prime is used for a pair of twin primes; an alternative name for this is prime twin or prime pair. (from wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime)
>
> Your mission, should you choose to accept it, is to write a function that counts the number of sets of twin primes from 1 to n.
>
> If n is wrapped by twin primes (n-1 == prime && n+1 == prime) then that should also count even though n+1 is outside the range.
>
> Ex n = 10
>
> Twin Primes are (3,5) (5,7) so your function should return 2!

I am trying to complete this challenge, my code seems to work for some values of N but for some it returns answers too small, and when N = 2 it should return 3 (according to challenge tests).

So far I have tried fiddling with the count += system, so for example:

```
if prime_list[count] + 2 or prime_list[count] - 2 in prime_list:
count += 1
```

but changing this has not solved my issue yet

(I am new)

Here is my code

```
def prime_finder(n):
    primes = []
    for possibleprime in range(2, n + 1):
        isprime = True
        for num in range(2, possibleprime):
            if possibleprime % num == 0:
                isprime = False
        if isprime:
            primes.append(possibleprime)
    return primes


def twin_prime(n):
    prime_list = prime_finder(n)
    count = 0
    for i in prime_list:
        if prime_list[count] + 2 or prime_list[count] - 2 in prime_list:
            count += 1
        elif prime_list[count] + 2 and prime_list[count] - 2 in prime_list:
            count += 2
    twin_count = count // 2
    return twin_count
```

Comment: `if prime_list[count] + 2 in prime_list or prime_list[count] - 2 in prime_list:`

Comment: had to change it to [count + (or -) 2] else it just gave 0 as 0 is not in the array, however now I get 'list index out of range' after an amount of loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` is one of the primes, so you should be adding to `i`, not `prime_list[count]`.

There's no need to add and subtract, because that will count each pair twice. Just add 2, check if that's a prime, and return that count, rather than dividing by 2.

```
def twin_prime(n):
    prime_list = prime_finder(n)
    count = 0
    for i in prime_list:
        if i + 2 in prime_list:
            count += 1
    return count
```